# Explaining the strict inequality with root $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, summation

> Sketch the graph of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, $x\geq 0$, and use it, together with relevant calculations, to explain why $$\frac{2}{3}N^{3/2}<\sum_{n=1}^N\sqrt{n}<\frac23(N^{3/2}-1)+\sqrt{N}$$

I drew the graph of root $x$ but I cannot see the link to the strict inequality..

Any hints would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard problem
that compares
$f(n)$
with
$\int_n^{n+1} f(x) dx$
or
$\int_{n-1}^{n} f(x) dx$
with the inequality
depending on
the sign of $f'(x)$.

Let's see what happens here.

If $f(x)
=\sqrt{x}
$,
$f'(x) > 0$.

Therefore,
since $f$ is increasing,
$\int_{n-1}^{n} f(x) dx
< f(n)
< \int_{n}^{n+1} f(x) dx
$.
Note that if $f$ were decreasing,
the inequalities 
would be reversed.

Summing from $n=1$ to $N$,
$\sum_{n=1}^N \int_{n-1}^{n} f(x) dx
< \sum_{n=1}^N f(n)
< \sum_{n=1}^N \int_{n}^{n+1} f(x) dx
$,
or
$\int_{0}^{N} f(x) dx
< \sum_{n=1}^N f(n)
< \int_{1}^{N+1} f(x) dx
$.

Since
$\int f(x) dx
=\int x^{1/2} dx
=\frac{x^{3/2}}{3/2}
=\frac23 x^{3/2}
$,
this inequality thus becomes
$\frac23 x^{3/2}\big|_{0}^{N} f(x) dx
< \sum_{n=1}^N f(n)
< \frac23 x^{3/2}\big|_1^{n+1} f(x) dx
$
or
$\frac23 N^{3/2}
< \sum_{n=1}^N f(n)
< \frac23 ((N+1)^{3/2}-1)
$.

This gives the first
of your inequalities.

To get the second,
go up to $N-1$
with the $N$ term separated.
This is a standard procedure
with these kind of sums.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} f(n) + f(N)\\
&\lt \int_{1}^{N} f(x) dx+f(N)\\
&=\frac23 (N^{3/2}-1)+\sqrt{N}
\end{array}
$

and we are done.

Comment: Understood, thank you!